# Unable to import android support IntelliJ project

Tags: java, android, maven, intellij-idea

I am trying to build a `JAR` **plugin** for an android application. The plugin has two dependencies :

android `AsyncTask` which I have imported using maven (and looks fine) and *android support* which I am unable to import it correctly.

**Specifically I need to import :**

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
```

When I make this call, `android.os` and `android.util` are red, as if they can not be imported.

I am importing android support by using the `Project Structure / Libraries tab`. I direct it to the `android-support-v7-appcompact.jar` file located in my android sdk folder. I have imported this library and included it as a dependency in my jar module.

What am I doing wrong ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is, you were trying to add `Android`'s `Handler` or `os.Looper` from android without adding any libraries or...

in java, we can use : `import java.util.logging.Handler;` instead of `android.os.Handler`.

And as you said, you have to add that android.jar for supporting above imports into your java project.

Comment: Is the a difference between the two handlers ? This jar will be used specifically for an android project.

Comment: Yeah well if you say you will use that for an android application, it's better to use that android.jar i guess.i didn't saw the sources so, let's say android is more compatible than that java.

Answer (score 1):

I was mistaken. I did not need android support. What I needed was android.jar. This was located in %SDK%\platforms\android-23\android.jar